# phonegap error app 620684 not found

Tags: html, cordova

Everytimes when i try to make an app and want to upload it to phonegap, i get an error:

```
C:\Users\Guus\Dropbox\html 5 app\test>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the remote environment
[phonegap] compressing the app...
[phonegap] uploading the app...
[error] {"error":"app 620684 not found"}
```

Am i doing something wrong??
I am using windows 8.1 and yesterday the app did worked

Sometimes i also get another error in html code
http://pastebin.com/PFqeA7LT or see below:

```
C:\Users\Guus\Dropbox\html 5 app\test>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the remote environment
[phonegap] compressing the app...
[phonegap] uploading the app...
   [error] <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator,
 [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred,
and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>




C:\Users\Guus\Dropbox\html 5 app\test>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the remote environment
[phonegap] compressing the app...
[phonegap] uploading the app...
   [error] {"error":"app 620684 not found"}
```